# change "label" defend on given class

Tags: php, jquery

I have `div` when `button to width large` click! the `div` width extend from `200px` to `970px` with the help of `jquery` [toggleClass](http://api.jquery.com/toggleclass/). is there any way when the width extend the label of the button change also like `button to default width`.

by the way, my [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/xwbh4vej/)

**js:**

```
$('.inlarge').click(function(){
     $('.googleMapWrap').toggleClass('divlarge');
     });
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [.text()](http://api.jquery.com/text/) like

```
$('.inlarge').click(function () {
    var $map = $('.googleMapWrap').toggleClass('divlarge');
    $(this).text(function () {
        return $map.hasClass('divlarge') ? 'button to width default' : 'button to width large';
    })
});
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/cjxdywjq/)

Answer (score 0):

Yes. This ought to do it:

```
 $('.inlarge').click(function(){
     var $googleWrap = $('.googleMapWrap');
     $googleWrap.toggleClass('divlarge');

     if ($googleWrap.hasClass('divlarge')) {
          $(this).text('button to default width');
     } else {
          $(this).text('button to width large');
     }
 });
```